# How to return ajax quired value in wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have created a ajax call back but it returns an error value. The code is bellow which I'm using.
I'm sending value from checkboxes when it checked. and want to return value from postedfile `listing_submit_demo.php`

```
jQuery(function() { 
    jQuery('.list_category').bind('click',function() {
        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
            jQuery('#some_textarea').html(jQuery(this).val());
            var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data: {idvalue: id},
                url: "<?php echo FRONTENDURL; ?>listing_submit_demo.php",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });                         
});
```

In `listing_submit_demo.php` I'm getting checkbox id value and retrieving values from database and then returning the listed value but it returns value with debug error. So how to get proper value from it? The `listing_submit_demo.php` code is bellow:

```php
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
$idvalue = $_POST['idvalue'];
global $cfield_tbl_name;
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * FROM  $cfield_tbl_name";
$val = $wpdb->get_results($query);
foreach($val as $x){
    $cate = explode(',',$x->field_cate);   
     if(in_array($idvalue, $cate)){
          $y .= $x->f_var_nm . ",";
    }
}
echo $y;
//?>
```

Any help will be thankful in advance.

Comment: within the "listing_submit_demo.php" file are you including the wordpress framework? ie: define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion that you can hook with the action "wp_ajax_$youraction" and "wp_ajax_nopriv_$youraction"

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29

The example is inside the link, wordpress ajax should work fine with these hook.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. any examples for doing ajax?